# How do you make neck and shoulders bend more naturally?

Tags: mesh, armature, bones

Is there a way to rig shoulders and neck so they don't clip in on themselves or look too deform? I don't know python code, so I can't make shape keys or driver bones. I just want the neck and shoulders to look good when they bend and twist.[image]

Comment: Maybe you can add another screenshot of the actual problem? Your mesh and bone layout look good. If the weights aren't messed up, the mesh should deform just fine when you rotate the shoulder and arm bone to raise the arm. To lower the arm, it should be enough to rotate the arm bone.

Comment: you don't need to know python to create drivers and shapekeys, if you can't get the result you want even with a good weight paint, then I guess you need to create a shapekey, which is not so complicated, maybe watch this tuto: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2vJqAxPly3o